# Pywin32 Outlook Filtering Emails with Restrict "LIKE"

Tags: windows, outlook, pywin32, win32com, office-automation

I am trying to make a program that uses the pywin32 library to download attachments from certain emails. I want to filter the messages in the inbox by their sent date, and their sender address domain. So I've tried this method to filter messages by their 'SentOn':

```
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox = outlook.Folders('inbox_name').Folders('Inbox')
messages = inbox.Items
senton = '2022-03-31'

messages = messages.Restrict(f"[SentOn] == {senton}")
```

This worked properly, but now that I try to filter by SenderEmailAddress using the @SQL syntax, like this:

```
messages = messages.Restrict("@SQL=(urn:schemas:httpmail:SenderEmailAddress LIKE '%@domain.com')")
```

I get no results, even though my testing set of messages should have emails sent by addresses cointaining @domain.com for example. What is the problem here? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Does the sender belong to your Exchange org?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to remove round brackets from the search criteria:

```
messages = messages.Restrict("@SQL=""urn:schemas:httpmail:senderemail"" LIKE '%@domain.com'")
```

If you want to add other conditions you can use the logical AND operation:

```
messages = messages.Restrict("@SQL=""urn:schemas:httpmail:senderemail"" LIKE '%@domain.com' AND ""urn:schemas:httpmail:date"" > '" & Format(senton, "ddddd h:nn AMPM") & "'")
```

The `date` property stands for the date and time on which the message was sent.

See [Items.Restrict method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.items.restrict) for more information.